# Jquery events not firing on blank input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running Django 1.5 and using Dajax/Dajaxice to asynchronously update a form. The form is just a description of an object (text feild). The value of the field is always displayed and is shown as an editable textarea. 
When the form is rendered, i assign an onchange event to the html form with javascript:

```
$('#form_id').change(function(event) {
                Dajaxice.appname.description_form(Dajax.process,
                    {'form':$('#form').serialize(true),
                    'pk':$('#parent_div').attr('pk')}
                    )
            });
```

This works with any kind of input except blank input. It seems like the event is not triggered if the textarea does not contain any text; what can I do to allow blank input to trigger the event?

It is not just the onchange event, I tried assigning others such as keyup() etc. with the same results (fully functional except for blank input).

Clarification:

by no input, i mean '' (no characters)

an input of ' ' triggers still.

Comment: You probably want to use `.blur()` then, this will fire each time the input loses focus.

Comment: Was a change actually done? Change does not fire if nothing changes and you need to leave the field. Does that method you are calling do anything if there is no value to send up? Should "#form_id" actually be "element_id" ?

Answer (score 1):

I remember encountering this before briefly, but some arbitrary changed resolved it.

In its simplest form, jQuery's .change() function should fire for a null input.  See this simple example, by entering text in the input, clearing it and tabbing out again: [simple .change() demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbqLgkju/)

```
$('#search').change(function(event){alert('Changed!');});
```

If you could provide more context to your code, maybe we could figure out what's causing .change() to fail.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks copeg. As you correctly pointed out, I can only comment on other people's posts when I have sufficient reputation, which I do not, as I only signed up yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, "input" is not the event you want to use. Since "input" is analogous to "change", it tends to produce a bad result when your string approaches 0 chars, use keyup instead
Try this:

```
$('#form_id').bind('keyup', function (e) {    
     Dajaxice.appname.description_form(Dajax.process,
        {'form':$('#form').serialize(true),
           'pk':$('#parent_div').attr('pk')}
     )
});
```